# Handle number in string PHP

Tags: php, string, string-parsing

I have a text area, it include string and number.

[image]

I want to sum 3 record into a text like this

[image]

I try to show you my stack, hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: the number will be only comma seperated ?

Comment: First i want comma and dot, but now, only comma is enough for me

Comment: Maybe you should just use 3 different input elements instead of a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know, how to do that this would work with comma, but this code

```
If(isset($_POST['test'])) { //test is my textarea name
    $total = 0;
    $ex = explode(' ',$_POST['test']);
    function total ($ex) {
        global $total;
        return $total+=$ex;
    }
    array_map('total',$ex);
    echo $total;
}
```

Worked well, when you write normal integer without anything (for example - 3500) and double with a dot (for example - 3.5). I think this function is good enough to use it

Comment: Yeah, your way work so good. But with comma and dot will be float ~^^~. Maybe i must prepare  for a valid floating point format, Thank you!

Comment: I think both double and float are with dot :D if you meant that

Answer (score 1):

With a little regular expression

```
$s = "xxx = 230.5
bbb = 490.3
ccc = 3.948";

preg_match_all('/[,\.\d]+/', $s, $match);
print_r($match);
exit;
```

Result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 230.5
        [1] => 490.3
        [2] => 3.948
    )

)
```

Please regard: if you use comma and dot, you'll have to prepare the values for a valid floating point format.