# Handle number in string php (Part2)

Tags: php, string, string-parsing

this is my problem 1 here: [Handle number in string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584233/handle-number-in-string-php) . I solved it.

Now, i see new problem, you can see the picture:

[image]

I want to get only number, not date (500000 and 200000) and sum it.

This is my code without date:

```
$total= 0;
    $ex = explode(' ',$_POST['txtSalary']);
    function total($ex) {
        global $total;
        return $total+=$ex;
    }
    array_map('total',$ex);
    echo $total."<br/>";
```

I try so much but no result, hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: show the actual content of `$_POST['txtSalary']` by printing it out. `print_r($_POST['txtSalary']);` show the value

Comment: `var_dum($ex)` and see what you are getting. You are not getting proper values from `explode`.

Comment: `$ex` is an array. Problem: you are trying to add array to integer

Comment: Does $_POST['txtSalary'] an array? 'Cause you can't explode an array. And why are you using array_map if u only need second part of explode? Use instead $total += $ex[1];

Comment: Please check this link:- https://eval.in/612692 .. If is it correct, let me know. i will post it as an answer. thanks

Comment: @Anant Yes! This result exactly.

Comment: Yes, please post it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `$_POST['txtSalary']` look like below:-

```
$_POST['txtSalary'] = '-27/07/2016: 5000000
-01/08/2016: 2000000';
```

So do like below:-

```
<?php

$_POST['txtSalary'] = '-27/07/2016: 5000000
-01/08/2016: 2000000';

$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['txtSalary']);
print_r($array);

$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $arr){
   $sum += explode(': ',$arr)[1];
}

echo $sum;
```

Output:- https://eval.in/612692